# Using regex to match the start and end of a media query, but not the content inbetween

Tags: html, css, regex, media-queries

I'm using the htmlcompressor (https://code.google.com/p/htmlcompressor/#For_Non-Java_Projects) to minify HTML content (HTML email templates) as well as inline CSS within the head section of the document. I'm running this via Command Line on Windows:

```
java -jar /path/to/htmlcompressor --preserve-comments --preserve-line-breaks --compress-css --remove-surrounding-spaces min -p /path/to/minify-preserve.txt --type html original-html -o minified-output.html
```

Within this document there are two media queries which I need to prevent the htmlcompressor from modifying due to syntax issues. I was looking around and found this regex rule:

```
@media[^{]+\{([\s\S]+?})\s*}
```

It however matches the media queries and the contents between, ideally, I need it to match only the starting block and end brackets, so its maintains spaces in these areas for valid syntax.

Would this be achievable with regex? I am limited to regex only as its the only method of creating preservation rules, as per the documentation.

Thanks.

Comment: I think I am missing some point here because IMO, can't we cut those lines and paste after compressing?

Comment: Yes, I was wondering if I could automate the process entirely though. There are other preserve rules for other areas I managed to create with regex, media queries however, is the area I'm stuck on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'r regular expresion is almost right. but (backward slash) is missing before closing curly brace

```
@media[^{]+\{([\s\S]+?\})\s*\}
```

Comment: should be marked as correct answer. very helpful. thanks