# Recursive/subroutine regex to match CSS media queries

Tags: php, css, regex, recursion, pcre

I'm looking for a regular expression (in PHP PCRE) that can match media queries and their contents reliably, *including* the somewhat odd case where a media query body is empty. Source text might be:

```
@media only screen {
    p {
        color:red;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 596px) {
    p {
        color:blue;
    }
    img {
        max-width: 200px;
    }
}
@media only screen {

}
img {
    display: block;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 240px) {
    p {
        color:green;
    }
}
p {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

I want to capture each media query and its CSS body as subpatterns, so I'll end up with a PHP array like:

```
[['@media only screen {
        p {
            color:red;
        }
    }','p {
            color:red;
        }'],...]
```

The key thing is that this needs to be a recursive or subroutine pattern in order to balance the braces. The empty query is enough to confuse the pattern in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24183531/using-regex-to-match-the-start-and-end-of-a-media-query-but-not-the-content-inb) because it can't distinguish the end of a css rule from the end of the empty media query:

```
/@media[^{]+\{([\s\S]+?\})\s*\}/
```

I've been trying and failing to use the advice in [this article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) to make a pattern of the form `(b(?:m|(?1))*e)`, where `b` is what begins the construct, `m` is what can occur in the middle of the construct, and `e` is what can occur at the end, and none of them can match the same thing.

So, `b` should be `@media[^{]+\{`, `e` should be `\}`, and `m` needs to consume CSS rules, perhaps `([^{]+?\{[^}]*?\s*\})`, giving me:

```
/(@media[^{]+\{(?:([^{]+?\{[^}]*?\}\s*)*|(?1))*\})/s
```

However, that doesn't work so I'm a bit lost. Can anyone suggest an effective pattern?

I've set up a regex test [here](https://regex101.com/r/xC6eQ0/1).

Alternatively, a non-regex parser might work better.

Note that I'm not attempting to validate or match CSS selectors in general (not a job for a regex), just grab the content of the query and its body.

**Update** added more sample content, explained what I want to get out.

Comment: Are you looking for [`'~@media\b[^{]*({(?>[^{}]++|(?1))*})~'`](https://regex101.com/r/qC1hO8/2)?

Comment: No, it could be any valid media query.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew should it be `[^{}]++` or `[^{}]+`?

Comment: @rock321987: A usual non-possessive quantifier will work the same here, so can be any.

Comment: That's pretty close, thanks. I want the captured groups to be slightly different, I've updated the question to show that.

Comment: It is impossible to do that in 1 regex matching operation with PCRE. Or next to. You can use [`'~@media\b[^{]*({((?:[^{}]+|(?1))*)})~'`](https://regex101.com/r/qC1hO8/3) and then split the contents of the `$matches[2]` (or match with [`'~\s*(\w+)\s*{\s*([^}]*?)\s*}~'`](https://regex101.com/r/qZ3mH8/2)).

Comment: I've got a bit closer with [~(@media\b[^{]*(\{(?>[^{}]++|(?2))*\}))~](https://regex101.com/r/qC1hO8/4). All that's wrong is the `{}` around the css part, which I can strip afterwards.

Comment: Why did you use the outer `(...)`? You do not need them, match value is always present in `$matchesp[0]`

Comment: Ah, true, I was looking at rexex101's output, which doesn't include the complete match, only the subpatterns. I think this is good enough - care to put it in an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are sure the blocks you want to match always have a balanced number of braces, you can use a regex with subroutine like this:

```
'~@media\b[^{]*({((?:[^{}]+|(?1))*)})~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qC1hO8/2)

And here is an [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/U2UXzw):

```
$re = '~@media\b[^{]*({((?:[^{}]+|(?1))*)})~'; 
$str = "@media only screen {\n    p {\n        color:red;\n    }\n}\n@media only screen and (max-width: 596px) {\n    p {\n        color:blue;\n    }\n    img {\n        max-width: 200px;\n    }\n}\n@media only screen {\n\n}\nimg {\n    display: block;\n}\n@media only screen and (max-width: 240px) {\n    p {\n        color:green;\n    }\n}\np {\n    font-weight: normal;\n}"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($matches[0]);
print_r($matches[2]);
```

**Pattern details**:

- `@media\b` - match `@media` as a whole word (since `\b` is a word boundary)
- `[^{]*` - match 0+ characters other than `{`
- `({((?:[^{}]+|(?1))*)})` - a capturing group #1 capturing the `{...}` blocks with the balanced number of `{` and `}` (note it is a technical group, we need to recurse this group subpattern in order to correctly match the `{...}`s). It matches...

  - `{` - an opening brace
  - `((?:[^{}]+|(?1))*)` - Group 2 (the contents inside the balanced `{...}`) matching

    - `[^{}]+` - 1+ characters other than `{` and `}` (because we need to match everything that is not the leading and trailing delimiters)
    - `|` - or...
    - `(?1)` - the whole Group 1 subpattern
  - `}` - a closing brace

Note that `$matches[2]` can be further processed with [`preg_match_all('~\s*(\w+)\s*{\s*([^}]*?)\s*}~', $matches[2], $subblocks)`](https://regex101.com/r/qZ3mH8/2) pattern.